# Steam api avatar border color

Tags: php

I am currently working on my web with steam login and have a question. Is it possible to change your steam avatar border color in my web depending on whether you are in game (green), static (blue) or offline (gray). What I mean is does steam api give you information of currently ingame or something? I didn't manage to find it but I saw others do it. Thanks.

Comment: If you saw others do it then the obvious answer is yes, yes it is possible, however the "How" part of your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can check his state.

personastate
The user's current status. 0 - Offline, 1 - Online, 2 - Busy, 3 - Away, 4 - Snooze, 5 - looking to trade, 6 - looking to play. If the player's profile is private, this will always be "0", except if the user has set his status to looking to trade or looking to play, because a bug makes those status appear even if the profile is private.

Here you can find a lot of useful information.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API